# Show measurement with similar name in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a influx database which contains more than 300 measurements. Some of these have similar names. Is there a way i can search the names of the measurements with similar string in the names. Does influx have any syntax similar to sql where i can find similar table names using 'like' operator. Can i use something like

```
SHOW MEASUREMENTS LIKE =~ 'foobar'
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHOW MEASUREMENTS WITH MEASUREMENT =~ /.*foorbar.*/`

`SHOW MEASUREMENTS WITH MEASUREMENT =~ /regular expression/`